# Get value of selected option in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
    function Play() {

    var option = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
    var randomOption = option[Math.floor(Math.random()*option.length)];
    console.log(randomOption)

     var UserOption = document.getElementById('UserSelect');
     console.log(UserOption);
    
    }

    Play();
```

```html
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="UserSelect">
              <option value="1">Rock</option>
              <option value="2">Paper</option>
              <option value="3">Scissors</option>
            </select>
          </div>
```

I'm trying to save the selected option in UserOption. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: How are you calling `Play()` function ? I can not see this function being called anywhere in your code

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I am calling it after the js piece of code I showed. I just added it.

Comment: Change your `value` attributes to be the actual string you want instead of a number, eg `<option value="Rock">Rock</option>` then you can simply use `document.getElementById("UserSelect").value`

Comment: @Phil I just tried it, I get this error in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Then either your IDs are wrong or your script runs before the elements exist in the document.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to get the value of the select, like this:

```
var UserOption  = document.getElementById('UserSelect').value;
```

Then you can get the name from the options array like this:

```
console.log(options[UserOption-1])
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
function Play() {

var option = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
var randomOption = option[Math.floor(Math.random()*option.length)];

 var UserOption = document.getElementById('UserSelect').value;
 console.log("Player:" +option[UserOption-1] + " vs Computer:" + randomOption );

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="UserSelect">
          <option value="1">Rock</option>
          <option value="2">Paper</option>
          <option value="3">Scissors</option>
        </select>
      </div>
<button class="play" onclick="Play();">Play</button>
</body>
```

Comment: your code is correct but does not display the winners

Comment: @XMehdi01 The question was “how to get the selected option”, it didn’t ask for the winners.

Comment: We, as programmers, should add this on our own. Look at the code you provided

Comment: @XMehdi01 No we shouldn't add *anything* on our own! That's goes against the purpose of Stack Overflow. This isn't a resource to get complete functioning code, it is a Q&A repository where each question is about ***one specific task*** for the purpose of *future* users who may need to do that task. Adding unnecessary code for extra functionality that wasn't requested is unhelpful - as well as not being how SO works, it complicates the answer for future users by making it more difficult for them to identify the specific code necessary to achieve that specific task.

Answer (score 3):

You can call you `play()` function using `onchange` function on your select and passing `this` as the `argument`

In your `Play()` function just get the option `selected Index` and get it `textContent` to see what was selected

Also, please ensure that your `script` tags are added after the `</body>` end and **not** in `head` of the page

```js
function Play(e) {
  var option = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
  var randomOption = option[Math.floor(Math.random() * option.length)];
  console.log(randomOption)
  var UserOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex].textContent;
  console.log(UserOption);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="UserSelect" onchange="Play(this)">
      <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
      <option value="1">Rock</option>
      <option value="2">Paper</option>
      <option value="3">Scissors</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The option value is stored inside the value attribute.

```
  var UserOption = document.getElementById('UserSelect').value;
  console.log(UserOption);
```

Answer (score 0):

get value of user :

```js
UserSelect.options[UserSelect.selectedIndex].textContent
```

get random value :

```js
var option = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
var randomOption = option[Math.floor(Math.random()*option.length)];
```

**Full Code**

```js
let UserSelect = document.querySelector("#UserSelect")
UserSelect.addEventListener("change",()=>{
  var option = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
  var randomOption = option[Math.floor(Math.random()*option.length)];

  var UserOption = UserSelect.options[UserSelect.selectedIndex].textContent;

  console.log("User selected: " + UserOption);
  console.log("Computer selected: " + randomOption);

  if(UserOption === randomOption){
    console.log("It's a draw ");
  } 
  else if((UserOption === "Rock" && randomOption === "Scissors") || 
            (UserOption === "Paper" && randomOption === "Rock") || 
            (UserOption === "Scissors" && randomOption === "Paper")){
    console.log("User wins ");
  } else {
    console.log("Computer wins !");
  }
})
```

```html
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="UserSelect">
          <option value="1">Rock</option>
          <option value="2">Paper</option>
          <option value="3">Scissors</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

This code sets up an event listener for the `change` event on the `UserSelect` element. When the user selects an option from the dropdown, the event is triggered, and the code inside the event listener is executed.